# Unable to define constructor of 2 different class in the same file

Tags: c++, class, debugging, exception, constructor

I have 2 classes in the same file `employee` and `employeeException`. If i define a constructor for `employee` , i will be unable to define a constructor for `employeeException` , vice versa . Trying to define constructors for both classess would cause the following compilation error :

> no matching function call to employee

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class employee
{
    public:

            double operator + (employee);
            bool operator == (employee);

            employee(int);
            double getSalary();

    private:

           double salary;

};

class employeeException
{
    public:

    employeeException(string);

    void printmessage();

    private:

    employee e;
    string message;



};



int main()
{  
  employee A(400);
  employee B(400);

  employee C = A+B;

  if ( A == B)
  {
    cout<<"Yes";
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"No";
  }

  cout<<C.getSalary();
}

employee::employee(int salary)
{
    this->salary = salary;
}


double employee::operator + (employee e)
{
    double total;

    total = e.salary + this->salary;

    return total;    
}


double employee::getSalary()
{
    return this->salary;
}

bool employee::operator == (employee e)
{
    if ( e.salary == this->salary)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}   

employeeException::employeeException(string message)
{

    this->message = message;
}

void employeeException::printmessage()
{
    cout<<endl
        <<this->message
        <<endl;
}
```

**Questions**

1) From the above , it seems that we cannot define constructors of 2 different class in the same file , are there any way to overcome this

2) Can someone give me a explaination why we cant define constructors of 2 different class in the same file

**Additional info**

I am using Quincy 2005 to compile the code

You can use this online compiler: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp0x_online.php

**Conclusion**
It seems i have to add the default constructor employee() for it to work , thanks to everyone for helping me out one way or another

Comment: There is no such restriction.  What is the error you are receiving?  One problem I see is that employeeException contains an employee and employee has no default constructor.  Therefore, constructing an employeeException would generate an error... but that has nothing to do with the file that the constructor is implemented in.

Comment: Should work. What is the actual error you get?

Comment: which line do you get the error?

Comment: at the line employeeException::employeeException(string message)
{

    this->message = message;
}

Comment: You can copy paste the code and uncomment out the lines to see the error

Comment: ...Or you could do it on your environment with your compiler rather than a bunch of people from around the world all doing it themselves... We're trying to help you here...

Comment: @awesomeyi you didnt uncomment out employeeException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of employee in the constructor of employeeException.

```
employeeException::employeeException(string message)
  : employee(42)
{
     ...
}
```

Because the default employee constructor is private as soon as you declare another one.

Comment: employeeException is not a subclass of employee.

Comment: @John3136: `employeeException` has an `employee` member, and `employee` does not have a default constructor, so that member can only be constructed by using the initialization list.

Comment: Yep - you got me. Too much time away from C++

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (but haven't confirmed) that your error comes from the third line in your main function:

```
employee C = A + B;
```

The expression on the right invokes the operator+(employee) method, which returns a double. The expression on the left will attempt to construct a new employee object. However, you haven't defined an employee constructor that takes a double (or a default constructor and assignment operator that takes a double). There is only one that takes an integer.

The easiest solution is probably to change your constructor to take a double parameter instead of an int, especially because it is stored as a double inside the class anyway.